# Typo in Salary Calculator Slack preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, salary-calculator, typographical-error

When you paste the Salary Calculator into Slack, the preview text has incorrect grammar.

[image: salary calculator preview]

Specifically, it says:

> Use the Stack Overflow Salary Calculator to see how much you should **you** be earning.

It should say:

> Use the Stack Overflow Salary Calculator to see how much you should be earning.

Comment: Good catch. It is both in the `description` and `og:description`: `<meta name="description" content="How much does the average Software Developer earn? Use the Stack Overflow Salary Calculator to see how much you should you be earning." />` and `<meta property="og:description" content="How much does the average Software Developer earn? Use the Stack Overflow Salary Calculator to see how much you should you be earning." />`

Comment: Horrible typo! It should be *You use the You Stack You Overflow You Salary YouCalculator™ to see how much you should you be earning.*

Comment: This post showing up in the "Hot Meta Posts" box is a great example of how it elevates trivia all the time... we don't need every Stack Overflow user to notice every typo and burninated tag.

Comment: @Noumenon we don't need everyone to know about typos. We do need everyone to know about burninations, since it's a community effort. That's why they are actively featured. Think of them as signs advertising community garbage collection day. You might like walking ankle-deep in trash but you might still see that this concerns the whole community.

Comment: Users saying that they don't care about tags being burninated is a great example of how user based moderation on the site is dying, and people are fine with bad tags and related off topic questions floating around.

Comment: @BhargavRao: I never understood why community need to put such a great efforts to manage tags (burninate, merge, synonym etc.). I am not saying its not needed at all; but the efforts can be reduced tremendously just by changing the way of creating tags. We have procedure to alter (rename, merge, synonym etc.) existing tag, which needs involvement of community and approval from experts from domain. Similarly, there should be **procedure** to **create** the tag. Just putting a new string in Tags box creates it and then community have to clean the..... No wonder why community don't care about it.

Comment: @AmitJoshi, there are a lot of open feature requests requesting for tightening the creation of tags, but the dev team hasn't worked on it. So yeah, the community cares about it, but the dev team apparently don't. I don't mind them focusing on other more important issues, though.

Comment: @BhargavRao: All those feature requests are placed on wrong platform. Someone should place one on [Twitter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318341) may be considering Twitter Driven Development. -:)... `That's not the correct way! The correct way, if you want change, is to complain on Twitter! Meta discussions do nothing.`.     Just kidding...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. We just pushed a fix with less ***you***.